How to render widget only when visible in Flutter?
I have to use an InteractiveViewer, I can't use a ListView. But I got memory issue with lots of pictures. I tried to use Google Package: visibility_detector but I am facing lots of issue. What I am doing incorrectly ?
Steps to reproduce

I made a reproducible example:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:visibility_detector/visibility_detector.dart';


class LogoItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id;
  const LogoItem({super.key, required this.id});

  @override
  State<LogoItem> createState() => _LogoItemState();
}

class _LogoItemState extends State<LogoItem> {
  bool visible = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final key = Key("logo_${widget.id}");
    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey,
      child: VisibilityDetector(
        // key: UniqueKey(),
        key: key,
        onVisibilityChanged: (info) {
          final visible = info.visibleFraction > 0;
          if (visible == this.visible) {
            return;
          }
          print("Visibility changed to $visible ${info.visibleFraction} ${info.size} ${info.visibleBounds}");
          this.visible = visible;
          setState(() {

          });
        },
        child: _buildLogo(),
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget _buildLogo() {
    if (!visible) {
      return const SizedBox.square(dimension: 300, child: Placeholder());
    }
    return  Stack(
      children: [
        const FlutterLogo(size: 300),
        Text("Logo ${widget.id}", style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
      ],
    );
  }
}


class VisibilityDetectorBug extends StatelessWidget {
  const VisibilityDetectorBug({super.key});

  static const row = 5;
  static const column = 5;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Interactive Viewer with Visibility Detector Bug'),
      ),
      body: InteractiveViewer(
        minScale: 0.01,
        boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(double.infinity),
        constrained: false,
        child:  Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: List.generate(row, (rowIndex) {
            return Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: List.generate(column, (colIndex) {
                final id = rowIndex * column + colIndex;
                return LogoItem(id: id);
              }),
            );
          })
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Expected behavior
It should work correctly as shown in the video:

Actual behavior
It outputs incorrect visibility factor values as shown in the video.


You can try to get the minX, minY, maxX, maxY of the LogoItem and compare it with the current screen size to check visible
First you need to attach the GlobalKey to the LogoItem
    final key = GlobalKey();
    LogoItem(key: key);

When you change position then you can get minX, minY, maxX, maxY by
    final renderBox = key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    final offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    final minX = offset.dx;
    final minY = offset.dy;
    final maxX = offset.dx + renderBox.size.width;
    final maxY = offset.dy + renderBox.size.height;


